# How to fix theme thumbnails without uploading images to media library?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I post articles on my wp blog without uploading images to my server. So all images are loaded from the external source link.

That's why my post thumbnails are not properly resized by my theme. Because images are not on my server.

So can you please provide any plugin or any solution that can fix all image thumbnails based on my theme structure?

I mean, can you suggest any solution which will automatically resize necessary thumbnails sizes based on my theme without uploading?

Regards,